# Running x86 assembly code on a linux 64bit machine

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to run some assembly code on computer using mint 64 bit.
Therefor I'm running the following command:

```
as --32 tst.s -o tst.o && ld -m elf_i386 tst.o -o tst
```

When I try to run my object I'm getting an error:

```
./tst.o
bash: ./tst.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code or do I need to something special to be able to run 32 bit code on my 64bit machine.

I added the code I'm trying to run:

```
.code32
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
        call main
        jmp exit
.global factorial
.type factorial, @function
factorial:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        subl $8, %esp
        movl 4(%ebp),%eax
        addl 4(%ebp),%eax
        movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
        movl -8(%ebp),%eax
        movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
.global main
.type main, @function
main:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        subl $16, %esp
        movl $5,%eax
        movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
        movl -8(%ebp),%eax
        movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl -4(%ebp),%eax
        movl %eax, -16(%ebp)
        pushl -16(%ebp)
        call factorial
        movl %eax, -12(%ebp)
        addl $4,%esp
        movl -12(%ebp),%eax
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
.type exit, @function
exit:
        movl $0, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
```

Comment: Not every 64-bit Linux system can load and run 32-bit ELF executables. Just because you can compile it doesn't mean it can run on this system.

Comment: Your executable is called `tst`, not `tst.o`. You are trying to run the object file... better do `./tst` instead ;)  PS: you are missing `int $0x80` from the end too (possible copy-paste issue).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run this time. First I got an 'segmentation fault'. Once I added int int $0x80 it ran. Although the code is not printing anything, I was assuming it would return my an integer

Comment: @demathieu Returning is not printing...